# Can not download the leatest version of openvino from official download link

Tags: openvino

I tried to download openvino toolkit from the official link: https://software.seek.intel.com/openvino-toolkit, but failed. It just jumps to an error page.
I tried chrome and edge, both failed.

Can anyone give me another windows version download link?

Comment: I presume you follow the guidelines from the [official documentation for windows](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html). Latest version is `2021.4`. I can see it requires registration. It may depend where you're located and I suggest you try through a VPN.

Comment: thankyou for replaying. I have solved this problem. I have successfully contact their support engineer, and they gave me a direct link to download it.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem by contacting intel support engineers.
they gave me a direct link to download the installer.

This issue has now been remedied. For an optimal download experience, they recommended removing any ad blockers.

Answer (score -1):

We identified and fixed a bug in our registration system last week that may have caused a disruption to your experience downloading the Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ Toolkit. This issue has now been remedied and we invite you to return to complete your download. For an optimal download experience, we recommend removing any ad blockers.